# How to write Test case for mouseleave event

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular8, karma-runner

I wrote a testcase for the mouseout event, however it does not cover the entire function, instead stopping in the if condition.

Functionality
While hovering the mouse over the State Change in the picture. I'll display the submenu below; mouseleave should hide the submenu. I simply need to write a testcase for the mouseout method.

[image]

I believe the fake object `onMouseOut(event)` is incorrect. Could you possibly assist me in resolving the issue?

**HTML**

```
<li class="dropdown-item option-value" (mouseleave)="onMouseOut($event)">
```

**TS**

```
  onMouseOut(event): void {
    this.pageDividerActionOption.forEach(element => {
      if (event.target.innerText === element.option) {
        this.pageActionSubOption = [];
      }
    })
  }
```

**Spec.ts**

```
it(' mouse leave hide the suboption list', fakeAsync(() => {
  const data = { target: { innerText: 'Change State' }};
  const div = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.option-value'));
  let event = new MouseEvent('mouseleave', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      view: window
  });
  div.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  tick();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  spyOn(component, 'onMouseOut') // spy first
component.onMouseOut(data)
fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.onMouseOut).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Comment: How do you use the menu with keyboard only?

Comment: No, On hover only